# Proper way to execute this command

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table called `Blocks` that looks like this:

```
| startIpNum | endIPNum | locId   | 
|  int(11)   |  int(11) | int(11) |
```

Simple enough now. As you've guessed this is a list of IP ranges. I am using it for geolocation. Now I get the `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` and convert it to an integer and am trying to find the range the value falls between using this query

```
"SELECT * FROM `Blocks` WHERE startIPNum >= '$ip_addr' AND endIPNum <= '$ip_addr' "
```

where `$ip_addr` is the integer form of `REMOTE_ADDR`. Now the problem is that the query returns an empty result in both my PHP and MySQL in phpMyAdmin, even though I know there is a row in the table the IP number lies between as my IP number is `1677352691` and a row in the table is

```
| startIpNum | endIPNum    | locId   | 
 1677351936  |  1677354111 | 12431
```

So my conclusion is that my query is formed incorrectly. So how do I proper query the table to get the result I desire?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're giving incorrect conditions,

```
SELECT * FROM `Blocks`
WHERE startIPNum <= $ip_addr
AND endIPNum >= $ip_addr
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this without quotes, as they are of `int` type, and let me know the case then -

EDIT-

Quotes wont matter in the case , curtsey [peterm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1920232/peterm)

```
SELECT * 
FROM `Blocks` 
WHERE startIPNum <= $ip_addr AND endIPNum >= $ip_addr "
```

You can also use `BETWEEN` , like this,

one more thing you are setting `$ip_addr` in both matching  case

```
SELECT * 
FROM `Blocks` 
WHERE $ip_addr BETWEEN startIPNum AND endIPNum "
```

Comment: no luck with that ... I also tried `SELECT * FROM `Blocks` WHERE startIPNum >= 1677352691 AND endIPNum <=1677352691` in phpmyadmin with an empty result returned i will try the `BEETWEEN` now